# Extremely high memory usage with pyarrow reading gzipped parquet files

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have a (set of) gzipped parquet files with about 210 columns, of which I am loading about 100 columns into a pandas dataframe. It works fine and very fast when the file size is about 1 MB (with about 50 rows); the python3 process consumes < 500 MB of RAM. However when the file is > 1.5 MB (70+ rows) it starts consuming 9-10 GB of RAM without ever loading the dataframe. If I specify just 2-3 columns, it is able to load them from the "big" file (still consuming that kind of RAM), but anything beyond that seems impossible. All columns are text.

I am currently using pandas.read_parquet, but I have also tried pyarrow.read_table with same results.

Any ideas what could be going on? I just don't understand why loading that amount of data should blow up RAM like that and become unusable. My objective with this is to load the data in parquet to a database, so if there are better ways to do it that would be great to know as well.

The code is below; it's just a simple usage of pandas.read_parquet.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet(bytesIO_from_file, columns=[...])
```

Answer (score 4):

There was a memory usage issue in pyarrow 0.14 that has been resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-6060

The upcoming 0.15 release will have this fix, as well as a bunch of other optimizations in Parquet reading. If you're curious to try it now, see [the docs](http://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/python.html#python-development) for installing the development version.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Looking at the issue however, they are talking about sizes that are significantly bigger than what I'm processing (GB vs MB) so I'm not sure if it's applicable, but maybe it is.

Comment: I downgraded pyarrow to 0.12.1 and that got rid of the issue. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!